# Rails Gem Kaleidescope Won't Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to use the rails gem Kaleidoscope and I'm having some trouble getting it installed. For reference here is the github site: https://github.com/JoshSmith/kaleidoscope

I include it in the Gemfile and it bundles just fine. But it does not install the config/initializers/kaleidoscope.rb.

I then tried to gem install directly, but it keeps telling me that
$ rails generate kaleidoscope:install
Could not find generator kaleidoscope:install

Does anyone have any ideas to help get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your gemfile entry for the kaleidoscope gem to this:

```
gem 'kaleidoscope',        :git => "https://github.com/JoshSmith/kaleidoscope"
```

The run

```
$ bundle update
```

This solved the issue on a Rails 4 app just now for me.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! Now I've installed the gem but I'm getting an undefined method 'with_color' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation[]>. Any thoughts on this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try restarting the Rails server.

Comment: Also, if my answer worked for you, would you be so kind as to choose it as the accepted answer? That's the bit of cheese for us mice.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I talked with the creator of the gem and apparently the gem is only 60% done and he is working on it. That's why the method isn't showing up. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: thing is, it is still broken when searching : `undefined method with_color for #<Image::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe6aee03a48>` server restarted or not